# PHP CUSIP Check num

Tags: php, algorithm

i need to be able to validate CUSIP numbers based on thier check digit. I have the psudocode for the process thanks to wikipedia, but i have so far been unable to replicate it in PHP.

Psudocode can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP#Check_digit_pseudocode).

My PHP:

```
    <?php
/**
    * function to return the check digit value of a cusip
    * @param $cusip
    *       the cusip for processing.
    * @return Int
    *       cusip check digit.
    */
    function cusip_checksum($cusip){
        $sum = 0;
        $rebuiltcusip = '';
        for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){
            $c = substr($cusip, ($i - 1), 1); //$i needs to be 0, so as we start at 1, take 1 off.
            $rebuiltcusip .= $c;
            switch(true){
                case $c == '0': // ctype_digit(0) returns false, so checking for 0 here.
                    $v = $c;
                    watchdog("case 0: ", $v);
                break;
                case ctype_digit($c): //check if numeric
                    $v = $c;
                    watchdog("case ctype_digit: ", $v);
                break;
                case $c == '*':
                    $v = 36;
                    watchdog("case *: ", $v);
                break;
                case $c == '@':
                    $v = 37;
                    watchdog("case @: ", $v);
                break;
                case $c == '#':
                    $v = 38;
                    watchdog("case #: ", $v);
                break;
                case !ctype_digit($c): //check letter last as this check would pass with * @ or # so allow them to be checked first
                    $v = (ord($c) - 64) + 9; //set ordinal number, -64 as this returns ASKII value, then add 9.
                    watchdog("case not ctype_digit: ", $v);
                break;
            }
            if(($i % 2) == 0){ //check if odd
                $v = $v * 2;
                watchdog("case odd: ", $v);
            }

            $sum = $sum + ($v / 10) + ($v % 10);
            watchdog("sum end loop: ", $sum);
        }

        $ncd = (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10;
        $rebuiltcusip .= $ncd;
        watchdog("rebuilt cusip: ", "Cusip: ".$cusip." Rebuilt: ".$rebuiltcusip);
        return $ncd;
    }
?>
```

watchdog is simply me logging the process.

Passing in a CUSIP of: 98986T108 which has a check digit value of 8, actually returns a value of 98986T104 (check digit value of 4).

so:

```
<?php
    print cusip_checksum('98986T108');
?>
```

should return 8, it returns 4.

Can anyone spot the reason for this?

Comment: You have to change `if(($v % 2) == 0)` to `if(($c % 2) == 0)`

Comment: actually should be if(($i % 2) == 0) rather than $c but very good spot there. will test

Comment: made the change, still getting incorrect values. 98986T108 now returns 4 instead of 8

Comment: Change
`case !ctype_digit($c): $v = (ord($c) - 64) + 9;`
to
`case $c >= 'A' && $c <= 'Z': $v = ord($c) - ord('A') + 1;`,
and place it after digits case.

Comment: same result as before =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the division in a floor() function and you are there:

```
$sum = $sum + floor($v / 10) + ($v % 10);
```

Now a Q in the CUSIP will have a value of 26. This will add 2 and 6 to the $sum instead of adding 2.6 and 6.

Here's the final function with the correction. I've run this through a Reuters extract of 17614 CUSIPs and there were 11 that did not match up. That's about the level of error I usually see from Reuters data so I have confidence in the routine.

```
/**
* function to return the check digit value of a cusip
* @param $cusip
*       the cusip for processing.
* @return Int
*       cusip check digit.
*/
function cusip_checksum($cusip){
    $sum = 0;
    $rebuiltcusip = '';
    for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++){
        $c = substr($cusip, ($i - 1), 1); //$i needs to be 0, so as we start at 1, take 1 off.
        $rebuiltcusip .= $c;
        switch(true){
            case $c == '0': // ctype_digit(0) returns false, so checking for 0 here.
                $v = $c;
                watchdog("case 0: ", $v);
            break;
            case ctype_digit($c): //check if numeric
                $v = $c;
                watchdog("case ctype_digit: ", $v);
            break;
            case $c == '*':
                $v = 36;
                watchdog("case *: ", $v);
            break;
            case $c == '@':
                $v = 37;
                watchdog("case @: ", $v);
            break;
            case $c == '#':
                $v = 38;
                watchdog("case #: ", $v);
            break;
            case !ctype_digit($c): //check letter last as this check would pass with * @ or # so allow them to be checked first
                $v = (ord($c) - 64) + 9; //set ordinal number, -64 as this returns ASKII value, then add 9.
                watchdog("case not ctype_digit: ", $v);
            break;
        }
        if(($i % 2) == 0){ //check if odd
            $v = $v * 2;
            watchdog("case odd: ", $v);
        }

        $sum = $sum + floor($v / 10) + ($v % 10);
        watchdog("sum end loop: ", $sum);
    }

    $ncd = (10 - ($sum % 10)) % 10;
    $rebuiltcusip .= $ncd;
    watchdog("rebuilt cusip: ", "Cusip: ".$cusip." Rebuilt: ".$rebuiltcusip);
    return $ncd;
}
```

Comment: accepted, i completely forgot to do this, so done while reviewing past Q/As